# Imagen css no se redimensionan en Grid

Tags: html, css, imagen

Por favor, porque no cambian de tamaño?

(!--NO AGREGUE MAS IMAGENES AL HTML XQUE NO SE REDIMESIONAN-->
si hago todo este codigo, pero sin agregar imagenes, solo contenido alfanumerico funciona bien, pero con imagenes NO)

HTML:

```
<div class="imagen"><img src="/imagenes/perro salchicha.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="/imagenes/leaves33.webp" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<div class="imagen"><img src="" alt=""></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
gap: 20px;
padding: 20px;
grid-auto-flow: dense
```

}

```
.imagen {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
```

}
.grid-items{

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border-radius: 4px;
transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
border: solid 1px white;
```

}

```
.grid-container:hover{
filter: opacity(0.9);
transform: scale(1.04);
```

}

```
.item1 {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end: -1;
```

}

```
.wide{
grid-column: span 2;
```

}

```
.tall{
grid-row: span 2;
```

}

Comment: QUISE DECIR CSS, NO CDSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si eso fue todo tu **CSS**, entonces te faltó ajusta la imagen misma a su contenedor, de esta forma:

```
.imagen img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: GRACIAS!!!! ERA ESO !!!